# How to remove extra character added while concatinating string in a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

am concatinating a string inside a for loop

```
var s="";
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    s=s+"'"+"id"+i+"',";
}
document.write(s);
```

Output I got is

```
'id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6','id7','id8','id9','id10',
```

I am trying to get the result as

```
'id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6','id7','id8','id9','id10'
```

How can I remove the extra `,` added an the end?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/9nc5h2jr/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a array of strings and then join the string like

```
var s = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    s.push("'id" + i + "'");
}
var string = s.join();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hprxk91h/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the substring method:

```
var s="";
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    s=s+"'"+"id"+i+"',";
}
s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
document.write(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

using JavaScript String `slice()` method

```
str.slice(0,-1);
```

The `slice()` method extracts a section of a string and returns a new string
- [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)